# Estimating numerically $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\sin 4x} x$

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

As the title says, I am looking for ways to estimate numerically $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\sin 4x} x$. So far, I've tried filling in numbers on either end of zero to make an estimate, and keep getting answers around $.0697$ or $.0698$, but the homework website I am on is marking me wrong.

Am I solving this the wrong way? Does anyone know how else I should go about this?
Please let me know.

Comment: Mathematically the limit is $4$, so you should find numerically something close to $4$. But I don't understand what exactly you did.

Comment: I most likely went about this the entirely wrong way then, since I never ended up with 4. The site accepted that as the correct answer, but how did you get it?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I could not understand the phrase 'as the limit approaches 0'. Are you looking for this solution? $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin 4x}x\\=4\lim\limits_{4x\to 0} \frac {\sin 4x}{4x}\\=4$

Comment: yes! I definitely phrased that wrong but that's the problem. Thank you for showing the work for it too

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: You got 0.0697 because you did something like this on your calculator: enter 0.04 , calculate sin, divide by 0.01. The problem is that your calculator is calculating in degrees, and you should switch to radians.

Comment: thank you! I hadn't realized it wasn't in radians until now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using degrees where you should be using radians.

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x} x = \text{a nonzero number, equal to $1$ if radians are used.}
$$
$$
\frac d {dx} \sin x = C\cdot\cos x,\text{ and $C=1$ if radians are used.}
$$
There is a reason why radians are used in calculus, and this is it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Taylor series expansion for $\sin(4x)$ and divide by $x$ to get:

$$\frac{\sin(4x)}{x}=\frac{4x-32x^3/3+128x^5/15+\cdots}{x}$$

Clearly the limit here is $4$ as $x$ approaches zero.

You could argue that since Taylor series is not exact, then this approach using estimation or not, well, I just wanted to show you another way.